# Unable to Remove Azure Databricks Managed Resource Group

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I created Azure Databricks in my resource group. This created the managed resource group with a storage account. My resource group also contains other database services such as Cosmos DB and SQL Server.

I removed the resource group after my work was complete. Unfortunately, the managed resource group did not get removed. **Note: I did not remove the Databricks service, I deleted the resource group itself.**

When I try to remove the managed resource group manually, I get the following error:

> the access is denied because of the deny assignment with name 'System deny assignment created by Azure Databricks

Under IAM, I do see the **Deny Assignment** that was created by Databricks. Due to this, the resource group cannot be deleted.

It's been a few days since my resource group was deleted, but the managed resource group still remains.

How can I remove this managed resource group?

[image: Databricks Managed Resource Group]

Comment: I have already asked the question in MSDN Forums (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/70f21330-2102-4744-b116-2c5fcf0911d2/unable-to-delete-resource-group-create-by-databricks?forum=AzureDatabricks) but the response was not helpful since I had already removed my resource group.

Comment: What is your role on this resource resource group when you look under the IAM blade?

Comment: I have the "User Access Administrator" role. "Databricks Resource Provider" has the owner role.  I tried adding myself as the owner but the action failed due to the existence of deny assignment.

Comment: double confim to remove your old resource group with PowerShell, `remove-azResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/<sub>/resourceGroups/<rgname>" -Force` ? Is this helpful?

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the comments.  I finally ended up talking with Microsoft support team. They were kind enough to allow me raise a free service request.  The managed resource group created by Databricks cannot be deleted from portal or through any script since it was created by the Databricks resource itself. Their engineering team is looking into it.  I tried to re-create the scenario and every time I removed the Databricks workspace, the managed resource group also got removed. So, not sure what happened this one time.

Comment: @RajuJoseph Would you like you post that as an answer so you can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The managed resource group created by Databricks cannot be deleted from portal or through any scripts since it was created by the Databricks resource itself. The deny assignment prevents deletion of the managed resource group. The only option is to contact support team.

Microsoft support allowed me to create a free ticket to raise the issue. The engineering team removed the restriction on the managed resource group and informed me that I can go ahead with deleting the same.

I was able to delete the managed resource group successfully. Also note that I  was not able to re-produce the issue (it must be a one-off incident).

Thanks for all the help.